# Animating variable width svg path

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have a handwritten signature to animate as if it is beeing written. I draw it into Illustrator as a path, but with the variable width tool I gave it a nice shape to look like it made by pen. I generated the svg code, but it made me a filled element with strokes, so I can only animate the stroke.
Is there a way to animate just the fill, or I can only animate stroke with equal width.
Or can I save svg some other way?

Comment: While you can animate the fill, you probably can't do it as if it's being written.